# Html & Css Table Cell Width Issue how to show Icon always on the right side?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a Table with 3 Table-Cells. 
The first one should represent a Profile Picture, the second one should represent a title (text) and the third one should represent a button with a flag icon in it.

**How it should be:**

[image: Here is a link because I can't embed images]

**How it is at the moment:**

[image: How it is atm]

As you can see the middle cell resizes its width automatically.
Thats the Problem because no matter how long the text in the middle is it should always fit/fill the screen. The Left and Right ones should always have the same fixed width.

**What I have tried already:**

```
<div class="table">
 <div class="tablecellleft">
  ........here is the img
 </div>
 <div class="tablecellmiddle">
  ..... here is the text
 <div>
 <div class="tablecellright">
 ...... button with icon
 </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.table{
 display: table;
}
.tablecellleft{
 display: table-cell;
 min-width: 17vw;
 max-width: 17vw;
}
.tablecellmiddle{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: top;
 //No width because it should fill
}
.tablecellright{
 display: table-cell;
 min-width: 17vw;
 max-width: 17vw;
}
```

Comment: May you could try to calculate the width of the middle cell: `width: calc(100% - 34vw);`

Comment: didnt work it ignores the calc and set the width to 100% witch results in resizing

Comment: You should provide a width, not only max-width and min-width.
Also you have two `.tablecellleft` but no `.tablecellright`. This makes reproduction easier :)
May you provide a fiddle for that example.

Comment: huh updated my question. my bad now we have the one for the right one.

Comment: edit: your calc worked like a charm but i had to change max and min width to only width: 17vw; thanks for your answer

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[calc](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)** and subtract what width you have given to left and right section by 100%;

```
width: calc(100% - 34vw);
```

```js
var fees = ['$0.9 + $.1', '$20 + $2', '$5 + $0.5', '$0 + $0.01', '$100 + $9', '$1 + $1', '$2 + $0.5'];
```

```css
.table{
 display: table;
width: 100%;
}
.tablecellleft{
 display: table-cell;
 width: 17vw;
}
.tablecellmiddle{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: calc(100% - 34vw);
 //No width because it should fill
}
.tablecellright{
 display: table-cell;
 width: 17vw;
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
 <div class="table">
 <div class="tablecellleft">
  ........here is the img
 </div>
 <div class="tablecellmiddle">
  ..... here is the text
 </div>
 <div class="tablecellright">
 ...... button with icon
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont want the middle text to be in the middle. The text in the middle cell should always be top left of the middle sell. Please remove that and updat your code.

Comment: Updated.Check Now. :)

Comment: perfect answer!